# MongoDB documents expiring too soon (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ttl

I set expiry time to 24 hours, but the documents expire after around 5-10 minutes (I haven't timed it exactly). What am I doing wrong? My schema:

```
const collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxLength: 30,
    required: true
  },
  entries: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Entry" }],
  expireAt: { type: Date, expires: 60 * 60 * 24 }
});
```

In the post route, I conditionally set the date so that inlogged clients get data persistence.

```
router.post("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  let date = null;
  if (!req.user) {
    date = new Date();
  }
  try {
    const collection = {
      userId: req.body.userId,
      name: req.body.name,
      expireAt: date
    };
    const newCollection = await Collection.create(collection);
    res.send(newCollection);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message);
  }
});
```

I thought I had a time-zone problem, but when I check the time stamp in MongoDB compass, it matches my time-zone. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you storing your data to a distant server?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the `getIndexes()` output for this collection in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this:

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, expires: '2m', default: Date.now }
});
```

Documents ware deleted after the second minute and I also confirmed that the TTL index was properly created (as a background one by default) with TTL of `120` seconds.

Try that time format and see if that works for you.

> Also note that any expected changes to the index via your mongo schema would not be reflected until
>   you manually remove the previous index and start your app to
>   auto-create the new one.

MongoDB version: **3.6.5**

Comment: That seems to have worked. All I did was change the name of the key from 'expiresAt' to 'createdAt'. I guess that name matters.

Comment: Awesome. If this reply has helped you please consider marking it as the answer so others can find it easier. Thanks!