# MongoDB data expires sooner than expected (node js, mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am currently using nodejs and mongoose and trying to set my document to be removed after 30 minutes. But this happens faster than expected, about 2 to 3 minutes after saving to DB.

After searching, I found and tested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558218/mongodb-documents-expiring-too-soon-mongoose), but it made no difference

this is my schema code:

```
// require packages
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

// create users schema
const EmailSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    code: {type: String, required: true},
    reason: {type: Number, required: true},
    reStatus: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    createdAt: {type: Date, expires: 1800, default: Date.now}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Email', EmailSchema);
```

and this is how I save data :

```
new this.model.Emails({
    email: email,
    code: code,
    reason: req.body.reason,
}).save(err => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    return res.json({
        massage: 'code saved successfuly',
        success: true
    })
});
```

The document is saved without any problems, but instead of 30 minutes later it is deleted after 2 to 3 minutes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525010/mongoose-expires-property-not-working-properly

Comment: thanks for the help, problem got solved

Comment: @SaeedNoroozi how do you solve your problem? can you please share the solution in answers? thank you

Comment: @AdilIjaz sorry for delay, I've solved it from the answer in the link that "hoangdv" shared